# Image repository to use with website for direct upload

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, imagemagick, image-gallery

I've created a website using angular 2 and I want to have an image gallery on it such that I upload images to a location directly from my phone, tag them as something (or put them in an album / categorize them) and then they can show up on the website directly. I want this gallery for my private site so it'll be rocking if the location I upload the pictures to isn't public either.

The website is responsive using bootstrap and a repo called angular-gallery or something which uses [imagemagik](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) to process pictures (after I put them on the server and run a build command). Imagemagik creates multiple variants of the pictures, small - medium - large etc so it scales well to mobile devices and the web in general.

Any suggestions on what I can use for this.. currently the app doesnt have a backend but i intend to use Node.

**Update** : I'm getting the feeling that I haven't explained the problem statement properly. What I'm looking for is like embedding google photos pictures on my own website. So every time I upload a picture to google photos, I'd like it to start showing on my website. I checked and google photos doesn't let you do that.. so I'm basically looking for something that does.

Answer (score 0):

you can try primeng which is a library of angular component from primefaces, there is the gallery component which can display images as you're saying, details on the link [PrimeNg gallerry](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/galleria) 
and for uploading images you can use the component file [Prime Ng File component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload)
using an is easy and it's explained on their home page.
hope this is helpful